# How do I pass data to the template file I created in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

How do I pass the $styles and $scripts variables to my template view file from IndexController that calls a child view? My current code will only send the data to child view.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public $styles;
    public $scripts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Set styles and scripts
        $this->styles = array(
            // css files go here
        );
        $this->scripts = array(
            // js files go here
        );
    }
}

class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    // protected vars here

    public function __construct(
        // interface files go here
    )
    {
        // vars here

        // Append styles and scripts to existing parent array
        parent::__construct();

        $this->styles['css goes here'] = 'screen';

        $this->scripts[] = 'js goes here';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        View::make('index')->with('styles', $styles)
                ->with('scripts', $scripts)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Added my view files

Template view file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<title>Title</title>
@foreach($styles as $file => $type)

    <link href="{{ $file}}" media="{{ $type }}" rel="stylesheet">

@endforeach
@foreach($scripts as $file)

    <script src="{{ $file }}"></script>

@endforeach
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    {{ $content }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Child view file

```
@extends('layout.template')

@section('content')
    // html for child view
@endsection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your variables as an array through to your blade template by adding it to the data parameter:

```
   public function index()
    {
        $styles = $this->styles;
        $scripts = $this->scripts;

        return view('index', compact($styles, $scripts))
    }
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure whether you have just shortened your code to make your question more understandable, but here are some of the issues I can see with the code you posted:

**Lack of `$this` in `index()`:**

Your `$styles` and `$scripts` variables need to be `$this->styles` and `$this->scripts` to get the class variables.

**Not returning a view in index():**

your index function isn't returning anything, you need to add `return` to return the view:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('index')->with('styles', $this->styles)
            ->with('scripts', $this->scripts)
}
```

**Yielding content with a variable:**

```
<div id="content">
    {{ $content }}
</div>
```

I can't see a `$content` variable being passed to the view, maybe it's in a view composer somewhere? but the normal way to add content is to use yield which injects the content section in to your view:

```
<div id="content">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to pass data to a view. I don't know how to pass data to a template view file from a controller that's calling a child view.

Comment: Is that your entire `BaseController` or have you shortened it? I can't see what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I added my view files. I'm trying to account for scenarios where I can overwrite the $styles and $scripts completely if needed in a specific controller.

Comment: And yes, that's my entire BaseController.

Comment: Laravel should send your data through to the entire view, so you can access it in the template being extended, I can see a few potential problems with your code, so I'll update my answer to see if they fix your issue.